# How to start another build on CodeClimate after the initial build fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, code-climate

Here's the first fail [build](https://codeclimate.com/github/kamok/devdb/builds/1). I forgot to configure file. So I added it again and recommit. Now it won't fire again.

Do I have to get a CI (using Travis CI) to first successfully test it first?

Answer (score 1):

You can press the refresh button in the top right corner on your repo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Support got back to me and told me it was a problem on their end.

> Sorry that your repository got stuck in that weird "limbo" state.
>   Currently, we don't automatically install our webhook for open-source
>   repositories and without that we don't see any subsequent commits if
>   the first analysis errors. Our dev team plans to improve this
>   experience, but in the meantime, I'd recommend installing our webhook.
>   This hook is what notifies us of certain events happening in your
>   repository including commits made to your default branch.
>
> To get that installed you'll need to run through steps 5-7 in this
>   help doc here: https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/github#pull-requests.